# Do I want pnorm or one sample t-test?

Tags: t-test, monte-carlo

I have an algorithm that calculates a metric from my real data, I have a simulation that generates random data of the same type and dimensions, runs the algorithm, and produces the same metric once for each random data.

Then I end up with a collection of null metrics and my real metric. I want to do a statistical test to ask the hypothesis how likely is it that my real metric came from the null distribution?

Is the correct way to do this with pnorm(real metric, mean=mean of null, sd=sd of null)? Or do I do a one sample t-test against the mean of real metric?

I know I can also get a Monte Carlo p value here as well, but then I am limited by the number of simulations.

Many thanks,

Chris

Comment: Is your alternative two tailed? If so, would differences in the metric either side of the middle be equally important; or would corresponding ratios above and below 1 be equally important (x0.8 as much as x1.25), or would it be something else (perhaps unknown)?

Comment: Alternative is: the metric did not come from the random distribution....

Comment: In that case t tests and z tests are sensitive to shifts in the mean, not to general shifts in distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case of a general "different distribution" alternative t tests and z tests are sensitive to shifts in the mean, not to general shifts in distribution.

From your initial post (and assuming identifying unusually large and unusually small values of the metric would be sufficient for your purpose and that you have enough runs) I was thinking 
you'd be able to look at the tails of the distribution of your simulated statistic (values of the metric tending to be larger or smaller than simulated), but this would not identify general differences in shape (such as more of a peak in the middle but smaller shoulders, with similar tail, say, or additional modes not far from the middle).

With only one value of the real metric, however, there's not a lot more that can be done, though a few possibilities suggest themselves

- if there's parts of the distribution you can *a priori* identify as especially discrepant;
- if the distribution of the simulated metric is smooth you might perhaps try to work with some form of smoothed empirical likelihood

Nevertheless, typically the "look in the tails" suggestion would be my inclination -- identify $\alpha/2$ of each tail of the simulated distribution as a rejection region and if the real value falls there, conclude that the real distribution differs from the simulated one.

If you only have a few simulated runs, a different approach may be needed.

Comment: Yes thanks. Actually we found the null datasets and metrics give very near normal or normal distributions using a lot of simulations, so that is why we used pnorm with reference mean and sd to get a p value for the real metric. Monte Carlo p values (without using pnorm) are dependent on the number of simulations, and we can only do 50-100 unless we wait a long time so it does not work well in practice. Would you recommend another approach using likelihood or any other approaches? I also thought about Bayesian methods because they are cool, but I could not see a way of doing it.

Comment: If you have near-normality the main differences to look for are in mean and variance. If the variances aren't very different you probably want to focus on the mean in which case t/z tests is it.